# Finding the top k matches in Pytorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, top-n

I'm using the following code to find the topk matches using pytorch:

```
def find_top(self, x, y, n_neighbors, unit_vectors=False, cuda=False):
    if not unit_vectors:
        x = __to_unit_torch__(x, cuda=cuda)
        y = __to_unit_torch__(y, cuda=cuda)
    with torch.no_grad():
        d = 1. - torch.matmul(x, y.transpose(0, 1))
        values, indices = torch.topk(d, n_neighbors, dim=1, largest=False, sorted=True)
        return indices.cpu().numpy()
```

Unfortunately, it is throwing the following error:

```
values, indices = torch.topk(d, n_neighbors, dim=1, largest=False, sorted=True)
RuntimeError: invalid argument 5: k not in range for dimension at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorTopK.cu:23
```

The size of d is `(1793,1)`  . What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This error](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/Giphy/celeb-detection-oss/3/492217296) occurs when you call `torch.topk` with a `k` larger than the total number of classes. Reduce your argument and it should run fine.